# error while dumping sequence files from hdfs

Tags: mahout

I want to dump my sequence files from hdfs to local and i tried with seqdumper.

How to resolve following error?

[image: error image]

I am using mahout 0.12.0 version.

I got the same error with clusterdump as well.

Answer (score 2):

The error message "Unexpected -s" tells us that the "-s" flag you're using is not expected by the job. Perhaps you mean to use "-i" for input? The expected options are listed after the error message.